# Is there any restriction for number of characters in TFS REST API?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to retrieve workitems from TFS using REST API. https://servername/tfs/collectionname/_apis/wit/workitems?ids='xxxx,yyyy,zzzz,....n' (where n count is 420). Each id is a 4 digit number. I could not retrieve more than 409 workitems. If the query exceed more than 409 ids, I receive "404 - File or directory not found" error. Please help me to find solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue,it has restriction for the length of the strings when using the REST API.

In this case, we can not get all the work items in one time, we can get the work items separately, just **call the API twice**.

Comment: Thanks Andy for re-confirming it.