# GetWorkItemsAsync fails when it retrieves 1800 workitems

Tags: tfs

`GetWorkItemsAsync` fails when it retrieves 1800 workitems. Example:

```
int[] ids = (from WorkItem info in wlinks select info.Id).ToArray();
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient tfvcClient = _tfs.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
List<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItem> dworkitems = tfvcClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(ids).Result;
```

If I pass array of Ids with 90 elements it works fine.

Is there any limit that it can get only n number of elements, how can we overcome this problem?

Comment: Any clear description you can provide to 'fails'? Any error?

Comment: Message: "One or more errors occurred."
  Source "mscorlib" 
  StackTrace "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   at TestCaseExport.FrmMain.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Users\\angolla\\Source\\Repos\\Export work items to excel from TFS\\TestCaseExport\\FrmMain.cs:line 4040"

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other info, appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a limitation of the URL length, it will get this exception once the URL length has been exceeded.

So, as a workaround you can limit your calls to a allowed range at a time (e.g.   200 ids at a time). Then call several times for the query.

> Unfortunately you’ve hit a limitation of the URL length.  Once the URL
>   length has been exceeded, the server just gets the truncated version,
>   so odds are high that the truncated work item id is not valid.
>
> I recommend limiting your calls to 200 ids at a time.
>
> ***Source here*** :
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/issues/49

Reference this thread for the limitation of the URL length: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

This similar thread for your reference: [Is there any restriction for number of characters in TFS REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381745/is-there-any-restriction-for-number-of-characters-in-tfs-rest-api/44385916#44385916)